# Невидимый коммит на сервере

Tags: git

Здравствуйте.

Возникла такая проблема:

Есть виртуальный сервер с проектом, над которым трудятся два человека.
Некоторое время назад один из разработчиков внес правки в проект на сервере (не коммитом, а по ftp изменил файлы) и закоммитил. Как он объяснил, он исправил некоторые ошибки в проекте.

И вот тут возникла проблема - данный коммит решил проблему на сервере, но на локальные машины он не сбрасывается (ни git pull, ни git fetch).

После данного "коммита", были залиты на сервер навые коммиты, и при этом не возникало никаких проблем. Но на локальных репозитариях данного коммита нет, и соответственно не решены те проблемы, для которых он был создан.

В связи с чем и меня есть вопросы:
Почему git c локальных репозитариев не видит коммит, созданный на сервере вручную?
Что можно сделать, чтобы он стал доступен?

Буду очень благодарен за терпение и ответы на эти вопросы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите репозиторий на сервере, скорее всего git push не был сделан, но на всякий случай и ветки посмотрите тоже.

П.С. Не забудьте дать больно по рукам, тому кто вносит правки на боевом сервере. В следующий раз это может стоить вам денег.

Comment: Насчет git push не очень понял? Ведь коммит на сервере, куда его пушить?

А коммит точно есть и он находится в основной ветке, а вот в локальные репозитории он падать не желает. Причем то что он (коммит) есть подтверждает отсутствие ошибков в проекте, которые есть в локальных версиях.

Я грешу на права доступа к репозиторию для разных пользователей, но решения пока не нашел.

П.С А насчет руки оторвать - это вы абсолютно правы.

Comment: Я предполагаю, у вас работа идет по принципу:

    разработчики - удаленный репозиторий - сервер

git на каждом из этих мест создает локальный репозиторий. т.е. у сервера свой репозиторий. Из которого нужно сделать `git push` на удаленный репозиторий.